# How to overlap the Android sliding tabs layout with background image

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-appcompat, material-design, android-support-library

**What I have tried:**

I'm developing an app with the new Android 5.0 Material-styled [sliding tabs](https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/project.html) with new AppCompat Tab bar.

**What I want:**

I want to put an image behind the bar and the tabs like Play Kiosko. Any solution for this would be grateful.

**Kiosko App Design:**

[image]

You can see the image behind that pager tab strip!

Comment: Use the PagerSlidingTabStrip Lib and make the tab strip color to transparent,  put that in framelayout such that you can see the Imagelayout in the Tabstrip background!

Comment: Thank, it works but not fully,now my tab strip is transparent, and my background is an image, but this background is only for the tab strip, not to the appcompat.

Comment: I've done more tests with PagerSlidingTabStrip and goes looking more to Play Kiosko!

Comment: You can answer your own question! request with moderators for removing the [on hold]